# How do I test Unity Mac app on android Unity Remote 5?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, testing

I want to test my app on android with Unity Remote 5 but it doesn't show it on my phone
I can do it with my Windows unity but not with my Macbook unity

At project setting I turned the device to any android device and I switched the platform to android.
The android build support is downloaded
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step – 1: Setting Unity App – Changing Build Settings and Project Settings (Selecting Android Device)
Launch Unity App
Click on File, then Select Build Settings
Switching Build Setting

Select Android, and click on Build. Now, wait until the process is complete. Once done, close this window. There is no need to worry as you can switch build settings anytime back to whatever you like.
Now click on Edit option, Select Editor under the Project Settings Window, and select Any Android Device from the Device drop-down list. Once done, close the window.
selecting Android Device

Step – 2: Set-up Android SDK Path to Make Android Remote Work
Make sure you have Android Studio installed. If not, please download it here.
Now open Android Studio. Click on Configure, and then Select SDK manager.
android studio

Check your Smartphone’s Android version and select the Android Version under the Android Studio app that matches your mobile phone’s Android Version. If it is already installed, you are good. If not, just click on the OK button and it will download the file.
Android Version and Path

Copy the Android SDK location path as highlighted in the image above.
Now open Unity App and click on the Unity option in the menubar, then select the Preferences option. Select the External Tools tab under the Preferences window. Now paste the Android SDK path you copied from the Android Studio app under the Android option.
sdk in unity

Step – 3: Configure Mobile Device
Download Unity Remote from the Play Store using this link or just go to the Play Store and Search Unity Remote. If you already have it installed skip this step.
Enable USB Debugging: Go to your Phone’s Settings, then About Phone, and then Tab to Android Build Version 10 times without stopping and you will enable Developer mode. Now go to developer option that usually shows up if you go back using the back button (may differ depending on the device). Under Developer, option make sure it is on, and you should also enable USB debugging.
After you enabled USB debugging, connect your Android Phone via USB cable to your Mac. If your device asks to select an option for USB connectivity, select PTP (not mandatory to do). After your device is connected, take a look at your Android’s Notification panel by swiping down from the up and make sure it is showing USB Debugging Connected.
That was all about configuring Mac and Android.

How to Use
Connect the device via USB Cable while USB debugging is on.
Open Unity App (if not already opened).
Open Unity Remote app on Android Phone.
Play the game on Unity on Mac and it should show up on Android as well.
If you face any issue disconnect USB cable, restart the Unity app on mac. Connect your phone again and retry, it will work.

I don't know if this answered your question... But hey! We're new contributors too in stack overflow!